# VS 2008 professional "close all documents" very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2008

VS 2008 pro closes its editor windows very slowly on my machine. A similar installation on a similar machine is significantly faster.

I have tried several tricks I found with Google to remedy this, but to no avail.

Hardware: `Core i7 920 @ 3.6 GHz, 6 GB RAM 1800 MHz, 1 TB Samsung Spinpoint HD`

OS: `Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits`

Here's the list of installed patches:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.4108 QFE
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008   91605-130-1673954-60589
Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008
Version 9.0.30730.126

Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-130-1673954-60589
Microsoft Visual C# 2008

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-130-1673954-60589
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-130-1673954-60589
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-130-1673954-60589
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

Crystal Reports    AAJ60-G0MSA4K-68000CF
Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008


Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB944899)   KB944899
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB945282)   KB945282
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946040)   KB946040
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946308)   KB946308
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946344)   KB946344
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946581)   KB946581
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947171)   KB947171
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947173)   KB947173
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947180)   KB947180
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947540)   KB947540
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947789)   KB947789
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB948127)   KB948127
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB953256)   KB953256
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB960075)   KB960075v2
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971092)   KB971092
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140)   KB945140
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB947888)   KB947888
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB948484)   KB948484
Microsoft XNA Game Studio   3.1
Microsoft XNA Game Studio 3.1
Build 3.1.10527.0
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB972222)   KB972222
Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB973675)   KB973675
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB956453)   KB956453
Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB967143)   KB967143
```

Comment: what's the problem?... you're impatient?

Comment: Do you have any code-versioning systems integrated with your Visual Studio? SVN or VSS, for example?

Comment: No, I haven't. No plugins or so at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some users report this problem with VS and Web Dev Express when running projects locally, and you can check that particular & solution issue out here : [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120720213818/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/21/workaround-for-a-very-slow-closing-of-web-projects.aspx)

Other than that, I can only suggest the usual "speed up" cleaning operations that you can do like :

- removing all of your breakpoints
- clean temp files, MRU list, disable autorecover & feedback ([See here](https://richarddingwall.name/2009/08/24/does-your-visual-studio-run-slow/))

I know firsthand that this will improve your average all-around performance, but I'm not sure if it will put an end to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had been on that page before and done all that. I am also defragging my HD on a regular base. It didn't help. I have a very similar workplace computer (hardware, OS, VS version), and that problem doesn't occur there. This is weird.

Comment: @karx It is weird! And it looks like you have all of the patches for hotfixes already. As a shot-in-the-dark, you can also check your computer's error log to see if anything odd is up (like disk errors?).

Comment: That's actually a good idea. There's nothing unusual visible though. I suppose there is some different setting between my two workstations causing the problem. It is incredibly hard to find out what it is though.

Comment: How long of a delay are we talking about here? Can you give some estimated times/examples?

Comment: Well, on the workplace machine closing let's say 20 editor windows takes about 2 - 3 seconds. At home it easily takes 5 - 10 times as long. There's a noteable delay (seconds, not fractions of a second) between closing each window. I have no idea what the IDE is doing or waiting for during that time though.

Comment: I have to correct my observation. The IDE first takes a while and does nothing visible, and then suddenly closes all windows.

Comment: I'm possibly seeing the same phenomenon, but with the added twist that the slowness varies per solution. A large solution closes windows much more slowly than a tiny one.